# Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 84, 1)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

This is my first attempt to LSTM layer and cant make this work. I have checked github bug tracker and SO topics but none of the available solutions solved my issue.

Whenever I change dense layer dimension or data shape I receive similar error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programowanie/GitHub Repositories/MYOPM/ui_main.py", line 640, in train_ml_algorithm
    self.ml.keras_LSTM_train()
  File "F:\Programowanie\GitHub Repositories\MYOPM\machine_learning.py", line 648, in keras_LSTM_train
    verbose=2)
  File "F:\Programowanie\GitHub Repositories\MYOPM\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "F:\Programowanie\GitHub Repositories\MYOPM\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 621, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "F:\Programowanie\GitHub Repositories\MYOPM\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 84, 1)
```

I got 3d-arrays which contain only binary data:

**train** - shape (20, 84, 147)

```
[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 1 0 0]]
```

**label** - shape (20, 84, 1)

```
[[[0]
  [0]
  [0]
  ...
  [1]
  [1]
  [1]]

...

[[1]
  [1]
  [1]
  ...
  [1]
  [1]
  [1]]
```

**Code:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(84, 147), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train,
          label,
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=64,
          verbose=2)
```

[image: model summary]

Comment: if your target has 3d shape set return_sequences=True in your last lstm cell

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I saw many guides regarding LSTM, why most of them suggest to set second layer sequence to False?

Comment: this is a choice related to your problem... if your target is 2d return_sequences=False (in last lstm cell), if your target is 3d return_sequences=True (in last lstm cell)